# Is there a way to make an android app respond to hardware buttons while phone locked?

Tags: android

I'm working on my first android app.  So far I have an activity that reacts to clicks on the hardware volume controls.  That's was easy to do, but I'm wondering if there is a way to make it so the app responds to these events from the hardware buttons even while the phone is locked?

I'm really looking for a confirmation of whether or not this can be done.  If someone could confirm and give me the general idea of how to do it that would be awesome.

Comment: sorry can't help but had to say are you sure consumers want this? seems to defeat the whole purpose of locking the phone.

Comment: It's possible, my FM Radio application responds to volume up/down while the screen is locked and back.

Comment: @SpliFF, I will be the consumer of this application, and yes, I do want this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I have not done exactly this but I believe that if you put

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

in your Activity onCreate() you will be able to do what you want even if the screen is locked.