# Android - blocking hardware buttons while locked

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I'm looking into making an app that prevents the default action on volume up / down key presses, and would like to get some input to see if I'd be wasting my time trying.

Here's the setup:

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3. I like to listen to music. Often i unintentionally change the volume of whats playing when the phone is locked and in my pocket.

At first i thought it would be simple; having tested a simple override of the onKeyDown() method for retrieving the integer values for the volume keys. Quickly i came to the realization that this would only work if i were to not lock my phone and keep ONLY that app open.

Next i found a few articles on Services, however i believe this also falls short for my needs as it's not a subset of Activity and so doesn't implement onKeyDown(); and unless I'm mistaken, a wake lock actually wakes and/or unlocks the phone?

Should I give up now, or is this actually achievable?
(actually it must be possible as the whole point of this is that i don't have to pay £3 for an app for this one feature. lol)

Note: Running 4.2.1
New to Android, but not to Java.

Steve.

**Edit:** Just a thought, but if i extended Activity to my own class (and override onKeyDown), and instantiated it in a Service as a static instance, would that custom activity persist while the phone is locked?

**Edit2:** I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434325/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-android-app-respond-to-hardware-buttons-while-phone-lo?rq=1) which suggests using FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED. I'll start looking at this when I get home, but I'm  still open to suggestions and advice :D

**Edit 3:**
OK so tell me if i start losing the plot here...
Using a broadcast receiver i will listen for the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF flag. If that gets called, create my custom Activity (with the onKeyDown() Override) and set it to FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED to take over my lock screen (i don't care because the screen is off). The receiver then listens for the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF, if called it will then destroy the Activity before showing the screen (or after, I'm not bothered if it flickers).
(possibly even just pause it, and only kill it if it detects an unlock).

Also a big thanks to @StoneBird for getting me this far, sometimes it helps to just hash it out with someone who knows what there talking about (hopefully ^_-).

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

[Settings.System](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)

You can start a service and set system volume like every 1 ms to keep it at a steady level. No key checking should be needed since the value is overwritten every 1 ms.

Also, there are free volume keepers on the market so you don't have to pay for that.

Comment: Is this how people achieve this type of functionality in android powered devices? To have a constant loop (in its own thread I assume) which is constantly setting the volume value? Just seems like bad practice to me, but by all means correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I was searching about listeners but can't find anything related, so I come up with this idea, which is literally a brute force style stuff. But you can listen for `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` and `ACTION_SCREEN_ON` to control when you want to start the loop. These are system-wide broadcasts.

Comment: `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` is useful when you have an activity and want it to work when locked. But you have to start your activity first.

Comment: Ok thanks for the info so far, very informative; which leads me to this: could I use a service to listen for the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF action to start my Activity (with FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED)? or does the fact the screen is off / locked prevent the action from being displayed?

Comment: In your manifest.xml, you can register `<receiver>` that can load your broadcast receiver class, so you don't need to have a separate service just for listening stuff. With that flag your window will take over the lock screen. However since the screen is off I don't know if taking over the lock screen would be of any use.

Comment: Also see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED for a hint on `KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, if that would help.

Comment: Right, i think i got a plan worked out (See Edit 3). Gonna start working on it now, I'll post my results when I'm done.